# Find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (z^n - (\overline z)^n) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Find the convergence domain of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (z^n - (\overline z)^n) $$I do not know if it converges or not. How can I know? I tried to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|} < 1$ in order to use one of the conditions of converging. while $a_{n}=(z^n - (\overline z)^n)$ but I got: $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation - what does $\overline z$ mean?

Comment: if z=x+iy then z with the overline is x-iy

Comment: Complex conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  What are the real and imaginary parts of each summand?

Answer (score 1):

If $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$, then $\overline z=\rho e^{-i\theta}$ and$$z^n-\overline z^n=2i\rho^n\sin(n\theta).$$So:

- if $\theta\in\pi\mathbb Z$, then $z$ is real and the series converges;
- if $\theta\notin\pi\mathbb Z$ and $\rho\in[0,1)$, the series converges;
- in the remaining case, it diverges, because we don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n\theta)=0$ (not a trivial assertion) and therefore we don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho^n\sin(n\theta)=0$.

Comment: thanks alot. it was really helpfull.

Comment: How can I prove the convergence of the second situation?

Comment: Using the comparaison test: since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\rho^n$ converges and$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):0\leqslant\bigl\lvert2i\rho^n\sin(n\theta)\bigr\rvert\leqslant2\rho^2n.$$So, your series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the series $\sum z^n$ and $\sum \bar z^n$ has $|z|<1$ as domain of convergence, hence their difference converges in the open unit disk.

Furthermore, taking $z=i$, we obtain successively
$$z^n-\bar z^{\kern1mu n}=2i,0,-2i,0,2i,0,-2i,0,\dots,$$
so the series does not converge  for a $z$ with modulus $1$. We conclude the domain of convergence is exactly the open unit disc.